# Dynamic events in code

Tags: c#

I have a radio buttons and one text box on a panel made dynamically . Now, I want to disable the text box when the second radio button is checked, means they are both connected. how can I make the event for it. I want to have the event working.
Thanks a lot in advanced.
this is my code which is not working:

```
Panel pnl = new Panel();
pnl.Name = "pnl_";
pnl.Size = new Size(630, 80);

RadioButton rd = new RadioButton();
rd.Name = "rd_" + dr[i]["Value_Name"].ToString();
rd.Text = dr[i]["Value_Name"].ToString();
rd.Location = new Point(i,i*2);
pnl.Controls.Add(rd);

TextBox txt = new TextBox();
txt.Name = "txt_" + Field_Name+"_"+dr[i]["Value_Name"].ToString();
txt.Size = new Size(171, 20);
txt.Text = Field_Name + "_" + dr[i]["Value_Name"].ToString(); 
txt.Location = new Point(20, 30);
pnl.Controls.Add(txt);

//////  ???? ////////
rd.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(eventTxt(txt));

void eventTxt(object sender,EventArgs e,TextBox txt)
        { 
           RadioButton rd = (RadioButton)sender;
           txt.Enabled = rd.Checked;

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lambda to close over the relevant variable(s):

```
rd.CheckedChanged += (s, args) => txt.Enabled = rd.Checked;
```

If you had more than a one line implementation, you could call out to a method accepting whatever parameters you've closed over, instead of including it all inline.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to set the `Tag` of the radio button and get walk down the dependencies.

```
rd.Tag = txt;
```

In the event handler use this:

```
TextBox txt = (sender as Control).Tag as TextBox;

txt.Enabled = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use code given

```
rd.CheckedChanged += (s,argx) => txt.Enabled = rd.Checked;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could create an event for it:

```
//if you are using Microsoft Visual Studio, the following
//line of code will go in a separate file called 'Form1.Design.cs'
//instead of just 'Form1.cs'
myTextBox.CheckChangedEventHandeler += new EventHandeler(checkBox1_CheckChanged);  //set an event handeler  

public void checkBox1_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)     //what you want to happen every time the check is changed
{
    if(checkBox1.checked == true)    //replace 'checkBox1' with your check-box's name
    {           

        myTextBox.enabled = false;    //replace 'myTextbox' with your text box's name;
                                      //change your text box's enabled property to false
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!